# What's the adjoint of a zero operator? Is that also a zero operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

If yes, how can you prove it?

We have $\langle T(v),w\rangle =\langle v,T^*(w)\rangle$. If $T(v)=0$, then what?

Comment: If $T(v)=0$, what is $\left<T(v),w\right>$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the definition of adjoint, 
$$
\langle 0^*v,w\rangle = \langle v,0w\rangle=\langle v,0\rangle =0.
$$
As this happens for every $w$, $0^*v=0$ for all $v$. i.e. $0^*=0$.

Answer (score 6):

If $T(v)=0$ $\forall v$, this implies $\langle v, T^\ast(w)\rangle=0$ $\forall v$.

In particular, you can choose $v=T^\ast(w)$ and find $\langle T^\ast(w), T^\ast(w)\rangle=0$ and thus $T^\ast(w)=0$.